# Typescript compile error: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'Node'

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

Windows 7 x64

Compiling using gulp-typescript 2.7.7 using typescript 1.5 beta

Getting error: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'Node' because of statement
`document.getElementsByClassName('left-aside-wrapper')[0].classList.toggle('isOpen');`

I see that classList is defined in the lib.d.ts file as

`interface Element extends Node, GlobalEventHandlers, ElementTraversal, NodeSelector, ChildNode {
    classList: DOMTokenList;`

Not all that familiar with how d.ts files work so is this my error or is it a bug in the d.ts file that need to be reported?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `getElementsByClassName` is defined to return `Node` array and not an `Element` array.

> Not all that familiar with how d.ts files work so is this my error or is it a bug in the d.ts file that need to be reported

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName I would report it as an error.

Answer (score 21):

I have got the same issue when I want to update the classList of the fist child.

And my solution is

`const element = document.getElementById('testId').firstChild as HTMLElement;`

Answer (score 4):

Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild` (i.e. instead of `getElementsByClassName('')[0]`)

So

```
document.getElementsByClassName('left-aside-wrapper').firstElementChild.classList.toggle('isOpen')
```

Comment: You're right, sorry. With `getElementsByClassName('')[0]` it was implicit that it was firstChild, but it's worth to explain it